# ColdFusion, and documenting code as well as tools for multiple developer teams

Tags: coldfusion, diagramming, code-documentation, coldbox

I am beginning a fairly large new project using ColdFusion. This new project will include several developers and as such documentation of code will be key.

Another issue I am hoping to avoid (either with adequate code documentation or some other tool) is the duplication of code. A tool that would be able to "index" the code for searching or diagramming would likely help here.

What are others out there using either specifically for ColdFusion or language agnostic. We will likely be using ColdBox for the underlying framework if that makes a difference.

Thanks for any any all suggestions.

-c

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's impossible to tell you which framework to use without knowing more about your project, but I can list out some tools that will be useful no matter which framework you use.

Language-agnostic tools:

- [GitHub.com organization+teams](https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations)
- [Jenkins continuous integration](http://jenkins-ci.org/)
- [Apache ANT build scripts](http://ant.apache.org/)
- [Apache Maven for project management](http://maven.apache.org/)

Coldfusion-specific tools:

- [MXunit unit testing framework](http://mxunit.org/)
- [MockBox for unit testing](http://mockbox.riaforge.org/) (if you use ColdBox: [ColdBox-specific tutorial](http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/MockBox.cfm))
- [ColdDoc documentation generator](http://colddoc.riaforge.org/)

Javascript-specific tools:

- [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) or [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) for JS code cleanup
- [Jasmine unit testing](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/)

---

Ideally, your Jenkins build server should:

- Do a fresh checkout from source control
- Run all unit tests and stop the build if they fail
- Generate documentation
- Generate a production-ready package of your project

At a minimum, **I highly recommend using source control**, setting up Jenkins with MXunit tests, and scheduling daily automated builds.

Comment: I second using Jenkins. We use it on multiple environments and it helps our build times considerably. Also, we use it to manage our coding standards. For instance, any instance of HTMLEditFormat gets flagged and notifications are sent out (should be EncodeFor{context}). Also, ColdBox now has TestBox available as a replacement for MXUnit.

Comment: It seems that the link to ColdDoc is not longer available, and the project seems to has not been updated since 2012. Are you aware of any other Coldfusion-Specific tool for generating the documentation?

Comment: Looks like there's a relatively up-to-date fork of ColdDoc here: https://github.com/Ortus-Solutions/DocBox

Answer (score 0):

We used the Atlassian suite at my last job. Mostly Jira for tracking and Greenhopper for agile  but the other tools may help, fisheye, bamboo, and crucible. If you host it yourself I believe they have a one time $10/product price tag that. Depending on your team's size may or may not work.  If money is no subject the suite worked really nicely.  It also has built in support for svn and maybe more by now.

http://www.atlassian.com/software

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me what you need is a methodology, not a tool. If you have a clearly defined set of objects/responsibilities. There should be no crossover in scripting, and if you determine a common API for the objects being coded, I would think you'd be fine.

Comment: Agreed. One of the reasons I am pushing for the use of an underlying framework (leaning towards ColdBox). However, the use of some kind of code documentation tool would likely be very useful.

Comment: I think the best you'll find is a responsible programmer, I doubt any actual tool will do that for you. And yes I saw the ColdBox framework, but I meant beyond that you set an agreed standard for how the objects in your code are built.